# preg_replace with regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

This code `str_replace('A', ' Amp', $var)`
can convert **2.7A** to **2.7 Amp**.

But, it should not convert **A2** to **Amp 2**.

Can preg_replace with regex pattern solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind beased regex to match all the `A`'s which exists just after to a digit.

```
(?<=\d)A
```

Then replace the matched `A` with `Amp`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hV6aV0/2)

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\d)A~', 'Amp', $str);
```

Comment: It works for similar conditions. What is regex pattern so that CR1234A is not converted to CR1234 Amp?

Comment: try `preg_replace('~\.\d+\KA~', 'Amp', $str);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$re = "/A\\b/im";
$str = "2.7A\nA2";
$subst = "Amp";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

You can use this.`\b` will not match `A2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex -

```
A( |$)
```

[DEMO here](https://regex101.com/r/hV6aV0/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str="A2";
$pattren=array();
$pattren[0]="A2";
$replacement=array();
$replacement[0]="amp2";
echo str_replace($pattren,$replacement,$str);?>
```

Using regex pattern

> ```
>    <?php
> $str="A2";
> $pattren=array();
> $pattren[0]="/A2/";
> $replacement=array();
> $replacement[0]="amp2";
> echo preg_replace($pattren,$replacement,$str);?>
> ```

Demo : https://eval.in/299021

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change an A to Amp. at the end of any number you can try this (not regex though)

```
$strstr="3.4A"; //any value in this string


if ((is_numeric(substr($strstr, 0, strlen($strstr)-1))) && (substr($strstr, -1)=="A")){
    echo str_replace('A', ' Amp', $strstr);
}
```